# How to draw contour without filling in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, contour

Trying to extract numbers from an image, however I'm having issues with 0, 8 and such because of the enclosed portions.

When I use `cv.drawContours(black_img, [contour_num], -1, (255, 255, 255), thickness=cv.FILLED)`

it obviously fills the inside of the contour as well. How do I prevent this? How do I draw only the "outer" part of the number? Thanks

[drawn contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hREW.png)
[orig image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zTVO.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
cv.drawContours(black_img, [contour_num], -1, (255, 255, 255), thickness=cv.FILLED)
```

`cv.FILLED` is equal to `-1` and is the reason of drawing contours filled.

you should specify a value is greater than zero like `thickness=1` , `thickness=2` etc.